# How to remove terminal's delay when working remotely

Tags: command-line

Is it possible to avoid the delayed input when working remotely with the terminal? Ideally the delay caused by the network would occur once the command is entered/sent rather than each key input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the delay needs to be there. The terminal cannot guess if you are typing or there's some other event to be run on particular keypress. So after each key (or key combination) pressed your terminal needs to wait for the effect from the server. Which usually is adding a letter/character to the prompt.

You can press multiple keys in sequence without waiting for the answer, but you have to wait for the answer before the effect of typing would be visible.